# <=>でソートされる順番を定義したときに、同値だった場合のさらなるソート順序を定義したい

Tags: ruby

例えば、名前と給与を持つ`Employee`というクラスを定義し、これが基本的に`salary`でソートされるように、下のように実装したとします。

```
 class Employee < Struct.new(:name, :salary)
   def <=>(other)
     self.salary <=> other.salary
   end
 end
```

このとき、

```
 employees = [Employee.new('foo', 100000),
              Employee.new('bar', 150000),
              Employee.new('esehara', 100000)]

 employees.sort.each do |people| 
   puts "名前: #{people.name}  給与: #{people.salary}円"
 end
```

を実行した場合、出力は下のようになります:

```
名前: foo  給与: 100000円
名前: esehara  給与: 100000円
名前: bar  給与: 150000円
```

このとき、`salary`が同値だった場合、`name`のアルファベット順で並べたい(この場合ですと同じ給与である二人を、`esehara` -> `foo`で並べたい)とした場合、`<=>`のオペレーター部分、あるいは他の場所にどのようなコードを書き足すべきなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

次の参考ページがあります。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309723/ruby-sort-by-multiple-values

これにしたがって質問文中のコードの def <=>  部分を次のように書き換えてみました。

```
class Employee < Struct.new(:name, :salary)
  def <=>(other)
    [self.salary, self.name] <=> [other.salary, other.name]
  end
end

employees = [Employee.new('foo', 100000),
             Employee.new('bar', 150000),
             Employee.new('esehara', 100000)]

employees.sort.each do |people|
  puts "名前: #{people.name}  給与: #{people.salary}円"
end
```

実行すると、次の実行結果がえられます。

```
名前: esehara  給与: 100000円
名前: foo  給与: 100000円
名前: bar  給与: 150000円
```

Answer (score 1):

`nonzero?` を使うと、望む動作になると思います。これは、非零の場合にはその値自身を、0 の場合には nil を返します。

```
def <=>(other)
  (self.salary <=> other.salary).nonzero? ||
  (self.name <=> other.name)
end
```